# remove list items from list of list in python

Tags: python, list, loops, nested

I have a list of characters:

```
Char_list = ['C', 'A', 'G']
```

and a list of lists:

```
List_List = [['A', 'C', 'T'], ['C', 'A', 'T', 'G'], ['A', 'C', 'G']]
```

I would like to remove each `Char_list[i]` from the list of corresponding index `i` in `List_List`.

Output must be as follows:

```
[['A','T'], ['C', 'T', 'G'], ['A', 'C']]
```

what I am trying is:

```
for i in range(len(Char_list)):
    for j in range(len(List_List)):
        if Char_list[i] in List_List[j]:
            List_List[j].remove(Char_list[i])
print list_list
```

But from the above code each character is removed from all lists.

How can I remove `Char_list[i]` only from corresponding list in `List_list`?

Comment: specs, example, attempt - that downvote is harsh.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using explicit indices, `zip` your two lists together, then apply a list comprehension to filter out the unwanted character for each position.

```
>>> char_list = ['C', 'A', 'G']
>>> list_list = [['A', 'C', 'T'], ['C','A', 'T', 'G'], ['A', 'C', 'G']]
>>> [[x for x in l if x != y] for l, y in zip(list_list, char_list)]
[['A', 'T'], ['C', 'T', 'G'], ['A', 'C']]
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) with nested *list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> char_list = ['C', 'A', 'G']
>>> nested_list = [['A', 'C', 'T'], ['C', 'A', 'T', 'G'], ['A', 'C', 'G']]

>>> [[j for j in i if j!=char_list[n]] for n, i in enumerate(nested_list)]
[['A', 'T'], ['C', 'T', 'G'], ['A', 'C']]
```

I also suggest you to take a look at [PEP 8 - Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). You should not be using capitalized first alphabet with the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

```
Char_list = ['C', 'A', 'G']
List_List = [['A', 'C', 'T'], ['C', 'A', 'T', 'G'], ['A', 'C', 'G']]
for i in range(len(Char_list)):
    List_List[i].remove(Char_list[i])
print(List_List)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[['A', 'T'], ['C', 'T', 'G'], ['A', 'C']]
```

If the characters repeat in nested lists, Use this

```
Char_list = ['C', 'A', 'G']
List_List = [['A', 'C','C','C', 'T'], ['C', 'A', 'T', 'G'], ['A', 'C', 'G']]
for i in range(len(Char_list)):
    for j in range(List_List[i].count(Char_list[i])):
        List_List[i].remove(Char_list[i])
print(List_List)
```

Comment: I suggest using `enumerate` instead of `range(len(...`. Note that this solution removes the unwanted character only once (I don't know if that's what OP wants).

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is exactly what I want. I need to remove each unwanted character only once.

Comment: @yas.f If it helped you,feel free to upvote the answer. But I recommend to use the other answers , because they  have a better approach :)